# Codeigniter URI Routing not working till parameter

Tags: codeigniter, uri

In my router.php file I added this code.

$route['mission'] = "content/index/mission";

Here as you know content is controller, index is function and mission is parameter to that function.

But when i check it in my browser, it takes me to content/index . 
In other words, it is not passing required parameter to index function.

Comment: Can you show us your content controller?, and the index function?

Comment: I just looked over my content controller and found culprit. There my junior guy was getting parameter through uri segement :P Thats why it was not working. Thanks mate for making my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your recieving the parameters through the function parameters and not using uri segments.
Controller:

```
// This is incorrect, and will not work
public function index()
{
    $param = $this->uri->segment(3); // This wont work
}

// This is correct and will work.
public function index($param = null) // use null to prevent "undefined var error"
{
      if($param != null)
      {
          // The param was passed and do your stuff here
      }
}
```

Comment: No probs, I love codeigniter, amazing framework!, I use uri->segment(x) in my view files to test against if needed (am i on page x or page y?), otherwise just as above is the best practice for this.